# Efficient way of storig time intervals

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, datetime, many-to-many

In my Rails application i have a Shop model.

I need to store weekdays and corresponding opening hours like:
Monday 18:00 - 2:00
Tuesday 19:00 - 1:00
etc..

I expect to have a lot of shop records and i'm wondering what is the best way to store it provided that i care a lot about quick access.

One way is to make use of **Postgresql hstore** type.

I would keep a hash like `"Monday" => "18:00-2:00", "Tuesday"=>...`
 in an oppening_hours column in a shop table

Or I can solve it with a simple **relational** approach

```
class Schedule < ApplicationRecord  
  #weekday:string, start_at:datetime, end_at:datetime  
  belongs_to :shop  
end

class Shop < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :schedule
  #...
end
```

But then, any time i need to show info about shop i have to query 2 tables.
I am not sure if this is the optimized solution when talking about big table that is about to grow rapidly.
I would appreciate some advice.

Comment: i would recommend using the hash. just create a column called schedule and store the hash there.

Comment: Range types come to mind: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/rangetypes.html

Answer (score 1):

You may use the native ARRAY type. It is storage-efficient and will probably have decent support in ORMs.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/arrays.html

I would consider something like:

```
CREATE TABLE shop (
    ...
    schedule        text[][3]
);

INSERT INTO shop
VALUES (...
    '{{"Monday", "18:00", "2:00"}, {"Tuesday", ...}}');
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use your second approach but with some differences

```
class Schedule < ApplicationRecord  
  #weekday:integer, start_at:datetime, end_at:datetime  
  belongs_to :shop  
end

class Shop < ApplicationRecord
has_many :schedule
  #...
end
```

Here some consideration about this solution:

- First of all, I think it is suitable to store the start and end date in different columns. The reason is that you will be able to perform queries like "give me all shops which are open now" you will not have to parse each value in the column "opening_interval".
- I would use a number to store the day of the week. It seems intuitive that, when querying the database, it is easier to compare a column with a number than comparing it to a string.
- I think your relationship should be one-to-many in order to save up to 7 schedules for each shop.
- I would add an ActiveRecord validation to check that the weekday cannot be repeated for the same shop (a shop should not have two different opening intervals for the same day)